# Can I define the properties of neighbourhoods or open sets with only one axiom?

Tags: general-topology

Suppose we have a topology $(X,T)$, where $T$ is a collection of some subsets $N_i\subseteq X$. Any element $N \in T$ is a neighbourhood and it should satisfy the following axioms:

(1) $x$ lies in each of its neighbourhoods.

(2) The intersection of two neighbourhoods of $x$ is itself a neighbourhood of $x$.

(3) If $N$ is a neighbourhood of $x$ and if $U$ is a subset of $X$ which contains $N$, then $U$ is a neighbourhood of $x$.

(4) If $N$ is a neighbourhood of $x$ and if $N'$ denotes the set {$z\in N$ | $N$ is a neighbourhood of $z$}, then $N'$ is a neighbourhood of $x$.

**Question 1: can I replace the above axioms of neighbourhoods with (a)**

(a) If $N$ is a neighbourhood of $x$ in $T$ and $N'$ is a subset containing $x$, then $N'$ is a neighbourhood of $x$ in $T$.

---

Any element $N \in T$ is an open set and it should satisfy the following axioms:

(1) $X$ and $\emptyset$ are open sets in $T$.

(2) Any union of open sets is open.

(3) Any finite intersection of open sets is open.

**Question 2: can I replace the above axioms of open sets with (b)**

(b) If $N$ is $\emptyset$ or it is a neighbourhood in $T$ (defined by (a)), then $N$ is open.

---

I found that any subset $N$ which satisfies the axiom (a) will automatically satisfy all 4 axioms of neighbourhoods. Also, any subset satisfying the axiom (b) will automatically satisfy all 3 axioms of open sets. It seems to me that we do no harm to the theory of topology after replacing these axioms. Then why the mathematicans choose a bunch of axioms rather than one axiom?

---

**Notes:**

The topology $(X,T)$ need not to be a discrete topology. Those open sets in $T$ need not only to satisfy the axioms of open sets but also to meet the requirements that you specify, depending on what topology you would like to construct. The questions here are about the axioms only. The collection $T$ is not specified.

**And $(X,T)$ is a topology iff $T$ is a set whose elements are subsets of $X$ and these subsets are named neighbourhoods which must satisfy the axiom (a). (or open sets which must satisfy the axiom (b)).**

---

**Updates:**

An example topology: $X=\{x,y,z\}, T=\{\emptyset,X,\{x\},\{x,y\},\{x,z\}\}$.

And $X=\{x,y,z\}, T=\{\emptyset,X,\{x\}\}$ is not a topology according to (a) or (b) but a topology according to the usual 3 axioms.

---

**The questions are equivalent to "What is the consideration the mathematicians have to set up those ordinary axioms?"**

Comment: What does "open set of a point" mean? In topology, open sets are not attached to specific points.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Your definition of neighborhood leads to a topology in which every set that contains $x$ is a neighborhood of $x$. This, in turn, leads to the discrete topology, in which every set is open. So while your definition satisfies the requirements, not every collection that usually satisfies the requirements will satisfy your definition. You lead to only the second-most-boring topology that exists (that most boring being the indiscrete topology).

Comment: Sorry, I have edited the question so that it is more clear now.

Comment: "More general" is incorrect; your axiom is **less** general, in that while everything that satisfies your axiom will satisfy the usual four, not everything that satisfies the usual four will satisfy yours. That means that the collection of things that satisfy your axiom is **strictly smaller** than the collection of things that satisfy the usual set of axioms, meaning that you are defining something which is **less** general than the usual axioms, not "more general": it applies to *fewer* things.

Comment: @Arturo Magidin, It is more general. For example, we can change the (3) of the axioms of open sets to be "Any intersection of open sets is open" (no finite). You will find that if an open set satisfies my axiom (b), then it will still satisfy the (3) (no finite).  The axiom (b) is less strict than those 3 axioms.

Comment: No, axiom (b) is **more** restrictive than the three axioms, because anything that satisfies (b) will also satisfy the three axioms, but not everything that satisfies the three axioms will satisfy axiom (b). You are just wrong in claiming that (b) is "less strict". Again: the collection of all things that satisfies your (b) is **strictly less** than the collection of things that satisfy the usual three axioms. So your (b) is **more strict**: fewer things can meet its requirements. That's *more* strict, not less. A club that admits fewer people is a *less general*, *more strict* club.

Comment: By definiiton, a topology consists of every set that is "open". If you define "open" the way you are defining open, then you require all sets to be open. If you specify the neighborhoods of a point, this specification uniquely determines a topology by letting the sets in the topology be precisely the sets that are neighborhoods of all of its points; your definition requires **all** sets to be open. You are deluding yourself in thinking that you can specify neighborhoods without also specifying the topology. Just because you don't say "topology" doesn't mean you aren't specifying it.

Comment: The axiom tells us that what subset we can call it open. But these sets do not need to be open in the same topology. You can understand the axiom as that there exist some topologies that the subset can be called open if it sastisfies the axiom.

Comment: A topology is a specification of what sets will be called "open" (in that topology), and it must satisfy certain conditions. "There exist some topologies that the subset can be called open" is useless: for every set $X$ and every subset $A$ of $X$, there is a topology on $X$ in which $A$ is open. If that is all you are trying to say, then I have news for you: you are trying to define "subset", which we already have a perfectly fine definition for.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/146389/discussion-between-curious-cat-and-arturo-magidin).

Answer (score 1):

There's a slight issue with your phrasing of axiom (b): "call ... $N$ ... an open set of a point $x \in X$ if $x \in N$ or it is empty" suggests that the empty set is an "open set of $x$". I think you mean that an open set is a neighborhood of any point $x \in X$ or the empty set.

Given these statements, every non-empty subset of $X$ must be open, since non-empty means there exists an $x \in N$, and $X \subseteq N$ means that $x \in N \Rightarrow x \in X$, so $N$ is a neighborhood of $X \in x$. Since the empty set is also open, every subset of $X$ is open.
So your definitions describe the [discrete topology](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discrete_space).

But we're usually interested in topologies that are not the discrete topology, so that "open set" is something more interesting than "any subset". In the standard topology on $\mathbb{R}$, $\mathbb{N}$ is a subset of $\mathbb{R}$ which contains $0$, but $\mathbb{N}$ is not considered a neighborhood of $0$ and is not an open set.

---

Edited question:

> **1, can I replace the following** [standard] **axioms of neighbourhoods with (a)**
>
> **2, can I replace the following** [standard] **axioms of open sets with (b)**

Yes, in the sense that (a) and (b) define a particular example of a topology. That example is the discrete topology.

No, in the sense that your axioms are not equivalent to the standard axioms, and are not enough alone to be a basis for topology theory in general. (a) implies all the standard axioms for neighborhoods, but the standard axioms for neighborhoods do not imply (a). (a) and (b) together imply all the standard axioms for open sets, but the standard axioms for open sets do not imply (b). So you have described only one way of defining a topology, out of many, and restricted the general case to a very specific one.

Comment: Ahh, at this stage, I haven't define a topology yet. What I've done is just to give the axiom for what we can call an open set. For a different topology, we can define a different collection of these open sets which should satisfy the axiom (b).

Comment: @CuriousCat: You seem unfamiliar with what a definition provides. It's not just that everything you call an open set should satisfy the definition; it is also that everything that satisfies the definition **will** be an open set. So your proposal forces too many things to be called "open", because too many things will satisfy the proposal.

Comment: A topology is essentially a choice of which subsets sets are called "open", as long as that choice obeys the topology axioms. This initial definition of "open" gives the discrete topology. Yes, there are [coarser topologies](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_topologies) on $X$ (with more than one element), since the discrete topology is the finest of all topologies. But your axioms alone are not enough to say whether or not a smaller collection of open sets actually is a topology in the usual sense.

Comment: Thanks. I have edited the question. My question is about the axioms on the neighbouthoods or open sets, not the topological space.

Comment: Your edits have not changed the validity of this answer: your axioms (a) and (b) still are equivalent to the **statement** that the topology is discrete.

Comment: And to emphasize the latest comment of @aschepler, a list of axioms on the neighborhoorhoods or open sets **is** a specification of the topology on the set, i.e. that list of axioms **is** a specification of the topological space.

Comment: At the moment, I haven't defined a topology yet. I mean I haven't specified what collection of subsets of $X$ should be like, namely I haven't specify which open set is in the topological space. What I've done is, given an arbitrary topology $(X, T)$ ($T$ is a collection of subsets of $X$), any element of $T$ is call an open set and it should satisfy the axiom (b).

Comment: @aschepler, Thanks for your answer. I found (a) and (b) are more general than the ordinary axioms. So I wonder whether those ordinary axioms can be replaced or not. If they are replaced, what will happen?

Comment: Again, a collection of sets called "open" IS a topology. You can later choose a subset of those sets and maybe they'll be a coarser topology. But how will you know whether that chosen subset is really a topology?

Comment: Do you mean "are there other equivalent definitions of topology", or "can starting from different axioms give us something other than standard topology"? The answer to both is yes, but I think we'd need a more specific context to make that interesting.

Comment: Yes. It seems to me that, if we replace all those ordinary axioms with only one axiom, we do no harm to the current theory of topology. Then why do the mathematicians choose a bunch of axioms rather than one axiom.

Comment: @CuriousCat:  Yes, you do "harm" because replacing all those axioms with your proposed single axiom does **not** provide the same class of topological spaces as the current theory of topology does, the only thing it provides is what the current theory of topology calls the discrete topology. You effectively outlaw every topology except for the discrete topology. And the choice is not between "fewer" or "more" axioms; you could just take the conjunction of all usual axioms and make it "a single axiom." That doesn't make it "better"; in fact, it makes it harder to parse and understand.

Comment: Discrete topology is one specific case that those open sets satisfy my axiom. We can also construct a topology by refining those open sets with some restriction. But, after refining, those open sets still satisfy my axiom although they form a different topology to the discrete topology.

Comment: I can take any set $\mathcal{O}$ whose elements are subsets of $X$, and say that the elements of $\mathcal{O}$ are open and $N$ is a neighborhood of $x$ if $x \in N \in \mathcal{O}$. This satisfies your (a) and (b), but often this $\mathcal{O}$ will not be a topology. And just having any set of subsets at all is not as interesting as the properties of a topology.

Comment: @aschepler, Yes, that is what I said "I haven't defined a topology yet". What I want to ask is that why the mathematicians choose a bunch of axioms rather than one axiom. Is there any consideration force us to set a bunch of axioms instead of one.

Comment: Again, your axioms allow me to call ANY collection of subsets a "topology". So they are not enough to consider to get "topology" to mean anything particularly interesting.

Comment: My axiom seems to be equivalent to the axioms of open sets with (3) being "Any intersection of open sets is open". It looks fine and it allows you to construct more topologies. I don't see any problem here.

Comment: They are not equivalent. If $\tau$ is just some subset of the sets "open" per (a) and (b) (which is all subsets of $X$), you cannot use your axioms to prove that $\emptyset \in \tau$ or $X \in \tau$ or $A \in \tau \land B \in \tau \Rightarrow A \cup B \in \tau$, since $\tau$ could be anything at all.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/146368/discussion-between-curious-cat-and-aschepler).

Answer (score 1):

A "topology on a set $X$" consists of a collection $\tau$ of subsets of $X$ that satisfy three conditions:

1. $\varnothing, X\in \tau$.
2. If $A,B\in\tau$, then $A\cap B\in \tau$.
3. If $\{A_i\}_{i\in I}$ is any family of elements of $\tau$, then $\cup_{i\in I}A_i\in \tau$.

If $\tau$ is a topology on $X$, then we say a subset of $A$ of $X$ is "open" (relative to $\tau$) if and only if $A\in\tau$. We do not speak of open sets absent a topology, we do not speak of a topology absent open sets. If you define which sets are to be called "open", then you are defining a particular topology.

Now, if $\tau$ is a topology on $X$, you can use that topology to define what are called "system of neighborhoods" for each point $x\in X$. Explicitly, given $x\in X$, we define $\mathscr{N}_x$ to be the collection of all subsets $B$ of $X$ such that there exists $A\in\tau$ with $x\in A\subseteq B$. This is called the "system of neighborhoods of $x$" (relative to $\tau$).

So if $\tau$ is a topology, you can use it to say whether a set is or is not a neighborhood of a given point $x$ (relative to that topology). These collections satisfy a number of conditions: for each $x\in X$, we have that:

4. For every $B\in\mathscr{N}_x$, $x\in B$.
5. If $B\in\mathscr{N}_x$ and $B\subseteq C\subseteq X$, then $C\in\mathscr{N}_x$.
6. If $B_1,B_2\in\mathscr{N}_x$, then $B_1\cap B_2\in\mathscr{N}_x$.
7. For every $B\in\mathscr{N}_x$ there exists $C\in\mathscr{N}_x$ such that $C\subseteq B$ and for every $y\in C$, $C\in\mathscr{N}_y$.

One of the interesting things about topologies is that although they are defined via "global" conditions (properies 1, 2, and 3 above), they can also be defined via "local" conditions (conditions 4 through 7 above). Namely:

> **Theorem.** Suppose $X$ is a set, and for each $x\in X$, $\mathscr{N}_x$ is a collection of subsets of $X$. If the collections $\mathscr{N}_x$ satisfy conditions 4 through 7 listed above, then there is a unique topology $\tau$ on $X$ such that for every $x\in X$, $\mathscr{N}_x=\{B\subseteq X\mid \exists A\in\tau\text{ such that }x\in A\subseteq B\}$. Namely,
> $$\tau = \{A\subseteq X\mid \forall x\in A (A\in\mathscr{N}_x)\}.$$

When one says "I define the neighborhoods of $x$ to be...", one is automatically identifying a unique topology, via that theorem, even if the words "open" or "topology" never cross one's lips.  Different specifications of neighborhood systems will determine different topologies. One cannot define a general "neighborhood system", because what you call a "neighborhood" **completely determines** what topology you are describing. You cannot first say "all these are neighborhoods", and then try to say "but I do not want to consider the corresponding topology, I want to consider only *these* sets as open." Because the neighborhoods and the open sets are intimately connected: one completely determines the other.

That is one source of your misunderstanding. You cannot say "all these will be neighborhoods" without **also**, sub silentio, specifying one and only one topology. As it happens, your definition of neighborhood system, which is:

> (a) A subset $N$ of $X$ is a neighborhood of all $x\in N$.

is equivalent to saying that for each $x\in X$, $\mathscr{N}_x$ will consist of every subset of $X$ that contains $x$ as an element.

The **only** topology for which $\mathscr{N}_x = \{N\subseteq X\mid x\in N\}$ is the *discrete topology*, that is, $\tau$ consists of **every** subset of $X$.

So when you say "I want (a) to be my definition of neighborhood", you are also, necessarily, saying (even if you don't realize it) "I want every subset of $X$ to be open." That's the only way to reconcile that definition of "neighborhood". You can't then select just *some* of the sets you have necessarily designated to be "open" as "open", because as soon as you exclude some sets, you will no longer be allowed to call every set that contains $x$ a "neighborhood of $x$". You can't say "(a) will be my definition of neighborhood of a point" and then say "that will not define the topology $\tau$; I will put other conditions on what sets are allowed to be in $\tau$." That's not how things work, if you want "neighborhood" to mean what it means.

Now you could say instead that you are defining "flubs", and that in a topology, every neighborhood of $x$ will also be a flub of $x$; sure. But that is far less interesting.

Then you say your axioms are "more general" than 1 through 3; that is a curious definition of "more general", given that a collection $\tau$ of subsets of $X$ will yield neighborhoods that satisfy your definition *only if* $\tau$ is the power set of $X$. That is, there are *fewer* collections $\tau$ that satisfy your definition than collections that satisfy 1 through 3 above. I would call that *less* general, since fewer things meet your definition.

Finally, you ask why do mathematicians prefer 3 axioms when one might be enough? Well, note that I could have defined "topology" using just one axiom:

> $\tau$ is a tpology on $X$ if it consists of subsets of $X$ such that $\varnothing, X\in\tau$, **and** if $A,B\in\tau$ then $A\cap B\in T$, **and** if $\{A_i\}_{i\in I}$ is any family of elements of $\tau$ then $\cup_{i\in I}A_i\in \tau$.

That's just *one* statement. In general, we do not select systems of axioms by how many axioms you have; we select them so they are clear, easy to check, easy to understand, and usually because they capture some intuitive notion. "Fewer" is not the be all and end all of how we select axioms.